# added AFNetworking to new project got errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I created a new project, I simply dragged and dropped the *AFNetworking* folder into my project, and when I ran the project, I got these errors:

```
/Users/nadirahmed/Documents/iOS/afnet1/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h:40:1: Unknown type name 'NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN'

/Users/nadirahmed/Documents/iOS/afnet1/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h:51:1: Cannot combine with previous '(error)' declaration specifier

/Users/nadirahmed/Documents/iOS/afnet1/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h:80:4: Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (__nonnull or __nullable)
```

Here is what I tried:

- I cleaned the project
- tried to drag and drop the library into different areas into the project
- went to product, build

Comment: i do not wish to use cocoapods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` was introduced in Xcode 6.4 so please make sure you have (at least) this version.

Alternatively (and better IMHO) please consider using one of released "stable" versions of AFNetworking which you can find e.g. [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/releases) as they are usually more thoroughly tested.

Answer (score 2):

AFNetworking 2.6 introduces nullability annotations, these will depend on a modern version of Xcode 6 or Xcode 7. I would suggest you upgrade to Xcode 7 which supports these nullability annotations or use an older version of AFNetworking such as 2.5.4.